# Cognito authorizing a user through AWS lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, authorization, amazon-cognito

I use AWS Cognito and need to authorize a user through a lambda function. I have seen examples online and when I try to apply them, the Cognito authentication does not run and gets somehow skipped:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');
global.fetch = require("node-fetch");
const CognitoUserPool = AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool;
var AuthenticationDetails = AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails;
var CognitoUser = AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser;

var USER_POOL_ID = 'my_pool_id';
var CLIENT_ID = 'my_client_id';

var idToken = '';


exports.handler = async (event, callback) => {
    var email = event['username'];
    var password = event['password'];
    var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails({
        Username: email,
        Password: password
    });
    
    const poolData = {
        UserPoolId: USER_POOL_ID,
        ClientId: CLIENT_ID
    };
    const userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    var userData = {
        Username: email,
        Pool: userPool
    }
    var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);

    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: (result) => {
              var accessToken = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
              console.log(result);
              console.log(accessToken);
              idToken = result.idToken.jwtToken;
              console.log(idToken);
              callback(null, accessToken);
            },  
        onFailure: (err) => {
            console.log(err);
            idToken = err;
            callback(err);
        },
    });

    console.log("cognitoUser after: ", cognitoUser);
};
```

I can see the last console.log printed in the logs, but lambda does not seem to wait for the request resolution of `cognitoUser.authenticateUser`, as none of the console.logs inside onSuccess or onFailure get printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are couple of options

1. Remove `async` from `exports.handler = async (event, callback)`.
2. Keep async and wrap `authenticateUser` as `Promise` and use `await`

   ```
   const res = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
            onSuccess: (result) => {
                var accessToken = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
                console.log(result);
                console.log(accessToken);
                idToken = result.idToken.jwtToken;
                console.log(idToken);
                resolve(accessToken);
                },  
            onFailure: (err) => {
                console.log(err);
                idToken = err;
                reject(err);
            },
        });
    }
   ```

**Note:** Code has not been tested.